# remove comments from html source code

Tags: php, curl

I know how to get the html source code via cUrl, but I want to remove the comments on the html document (I mean what is between `<!-- .. -->`). In addition, if I can take just the `BODY` of the html document. thank you.

Comment: you should reparse them manually... I have JavaScript library of my own for that, but I don't know how could you implement that in PHP

Comment: there isn't a cUrl option for this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try [PHP DOM*](http://php.net/manual/book.dom.php):

```
$html = '<html><body><!--a comment--><div>some content</div></body></html>'; // put your cURL result here

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHtml($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//comment()') as $comment) {
    $comment->parentNode->removeChild($comment);
}

$body = $xpath->query('//body')->item(0);
$newHtml = $body instanceof DOMNode ? $dom->saveXml($body) : 'something failed';

var_dump($newHtml);
```

**Output**:

```
string(36) "<body><div>some content</div></body>"
```

Comment: Look it is working well, I have never heared about DOM. thank you.

Comment: To make multi-line of original HTML work and not showing `&#13;` for newline, change `saveXML()` to `saveHTML()`.
To make the result including `<html>` element, change `loadHTML($html)` to `loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD)` and change `$newHtml` line to `$newHtml = $body instanceof DOMNode ? $dom->saveHTML() : 'something failed';`.

Answer (score 3):

Regex solved this problem for me as follows:

```
function remove_html_comments($html = '') {
    return preg_replace('/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/', '', $html);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there's no option for this in cUrl (and I suspect there isn't, but I've been wrong before) then you can at the very least parse the resulting HTML to your heart's content with a [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) [DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) [parser](http://www.google.com/search?q=PHP%20DOM%20parser).

This will likely be your best bet in the long run in terms of configurability and support.

Comment: Correct, there's no such option in curl. It just gets the data as the server sends it.

Answer (score 0):

I would pipe it to sed for a regex, something like

```
curl http://yoururl.com/test.html | sed -i "s/<!\-\-\s?\w+\s?\-\->//g" | sed "s/.?(<body>.?</body>).?/\1/"
```

The regexes may not be exact, but you get the idea...

Answer (score 0):

I've run in to issues modifying a DOMNodeList in a foreach loop which went away went I [iterated backwards through the list](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php#83390).  For that reason, I'd **would not** recommend a `foreach` loop as in the accepted answer.  Instead use a `for` loop like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
for ($els = $xpath->query('//comment()'), $i = $els->length - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $els->item($i)->parentNode->removeChild($els->item($i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This work in my case:

```
preg_replace('/<!--[\s\S]*?-->/', '', $html);
```