# Tokenizer does not work as should in php

Tags: php, tokenize

```
<?php
$input = nl2br($_POST['input']);
$newStr  = '';
$commentTokens = array(T_COMMENT);
if (defined('T_DOC_COMMENT'))
$commentTokens[] = T_DOC_COMMENT; // PHP 5
if (defined('T_ML_COMMENT'))
$commentTokens[] = T_ML_COMMENT;  // PHP 4
$tokens = token_get_all($input);
foreach ($tokens as $token) {    
if (is_array($token)) {
    if (in_array($token[0], $commentTokens))
        continue;
    $token = $token[1];
}
/*test*/
    $newStr .= $token;
}
echo $newStr;
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
<textarea name="input" id="" cols="50" rows="30"></textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

For some reason it will not remove the comments, just the first line in the beginning and prints the code as it was.

Am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't add PHP open/close tags the comment will be `T_INLINE_HTML` token.

Look at the example at [token_get_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php).

UPDATE:

If you're posting PHP code `nl2br` doesn't make sense, cause it will add `<br>` tags to the code.
Try the following:

```
$input = '<?php '.$_POST['input'].' ?>';
```

UPDATE2:

If the source is only HTML you'd use a DOM parser. See example here: [remove comments from html source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305643/remove-comments-from-html-source-code)

If the source is a mix of PHP and HTML you also need a mix of tokenizer and DOM parser. So you'd use the code that you have and the content that you get for the token `T_INLINE_HTML` you'd parse with the DOM parser.

Comment: Is it PHP or HTML code or a mix that you're posting with the form?

Comment: ok but then `nl2br` doesn't make sense..see my update in a minute.

Comment: btw how would it look like with html or mix ?